# Basic conditional probability problem and question about event dependency

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

I have the following problem:

Given that P(A) = 0.7, P(B) = 0.5 and P(A|B) = 0.8, find 
a. P(A∩B)
b. P(A∪B) 
C. P($B^c$|A)

Here is my approach: 
a. P(A∩B) = P(A|B)$*$P(B) = 0.8$*$0.5 = 0.4
b. P(A∪B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A∩B) = 0.7 + 0.5 - 0.4 = 0.8
c. P($B^c$|A) = 1 - P(B|A) = 1 - $\frac{P(B∩A)}{P(A)}$ = 1 - $\frac{P(A∩B)}{P(A)}$ = 1 - $\frac{0.4}{0.7}$ = $\frac{3}{7}$ = 0.429

With problems like these, how can I decide whether the two events are dependent or not? And if they were, did I follow the right steps to solve these problems?

I can't help but feel like I messed up somewhere, and I would really appreciate some correction. I thank you for any and all contribution!

Comment: "*How can I decide whether the two events are dependent or not?*"  Two events $A$ and $B$ are independent if and only if $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\times\Pr(B)$.  Equivalently they are independent if and only if $\Pr(A\mid B) = \Pr(A)$.  Here, we are told directly $\Pr(A)=0.7\neq 0.8=\Pr(A\mid B)$ so they are known to be dependent.

Comment: "*I can't help but feel I messed up somewhere*" No, it all appears correct at a glance.  The only complaint I would have is that you used an equals sign for $\frac{3}{7}=0.429=\frac{429}{1000}$ when you really should have used an $\approxeq$ or written $\frac{3}{7}=0.\overline{428571}$.  Equals signs are to be used *only* for *equality*.

Comment: If they had been independent and you had been told $P(A) = 0.7, P(B) = 0.5, P(A\mid B) = 0.7$ then your method would still have worked.  But more likely they would not have told you $P(A\mid B)$ in that case and you would have had to find it or something as useful for yourself